# Colour problem when capturing a png of the top panel of the screen

Tags: utilities, imagemagick, screenshot, netpbm

I want to capture a window as a png from within a bash script, using the window's *ID*. In this case, the window is the top panel.  Using `gnome-screenshot` the colours are true, as per this image... (this image is not the same size as the following image, so ignore the dark line at the bottom)

[image]

However when I capture the panel via `import`, *or* `xwd` + `convert`, I get the following image..

[image]

Why would I be getting this colour aberration?

`import` and `convert` both belong to the `imagemagick` package...

I haven't found anything else in the Ubuntu repository which can capture a window by its *ID*... so I'm stuck.   (`gnome-screenshot` doesn't have the feature)... 
It would be nice to know what is going on here (eg, is is something to do with *transparent* images, which I know very little about)...but in any case, just a recommendation of a *workaround* capture utility may do the trick ... it must be able to capture a window by it's *ID*.

Here is an example of how I make and view the image capture.

```
import -window "$(wmctrl -l |grep "Top Expanded Edge Panel" |awk '{print $1}')" screen.png  
display screen.png
```

Comment: Weird. `ldd /usr/bin/program-that-displays-that-window` and `xdpyinfo` might give some hint.

Comment: I've just tried the process in a newly installed 10.04 VM, same as the Host (described above), and also tried it in a newly installed 11.04 VM... The same thing happens in all situations... I've tried different viewers, and even viewed one of the .pngs in a Vista VM (same Host) .. It only happens with *partial* icons; ie. icons which don't run to the very perimeter of their alotted space... It makes me think it is related the the *transparent* features of images ???

Comment: Another test on a dual-boot Ubuntu 10.04 (newly installed.. but the same machine) produced the same results... I seems(guessing) that it is either my *Graphics Card*, or *imagemagick*..  This is the command: `import -window "$(wmctrl -l |grep "Top Expanded Edge Panel" |awk '{print $1}')" screen.png; display screen.png` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making screens from console there is also `scrot`. As it is not a tool from `imagemagick` package I think that there is a chance that colors will be ok.

There is one problem - `scrot` can only take sceenshot of full screen, so we will take screenshot of full screen and then cut out area of window that we need. Of course for cut it out we will not use `imagemagick` but tools from `netpbm` package.

```
#!/bin/bash
unset x y w h
eval $(xwininfo -id $(wmctrl -l |grep "Top Expanded Edge Panel" |awk '{print $1}') |
        sed -ne "s/^ \+Absolute upper-left X: \+\([0-9]\+\).*/x=\1/p" \
             -e "s/^ \+Absolute upper-left Y: \+\([0-9]\+\).*/y=\1/p" \
             -e "s/^ \+Width: \+\([0-9]\+\).*/w=\1/p" \
             -e "s/^ \+Height: \+\([0-9]\+\).*/h=\1/p" )
scrot scrot.pnm
    < scrot.pnm pnmcut -left $x -top $y -width $w -height $h | pnmtopng > scrot_cropped.png
display scrot_cropped.png
```

Could you check if with `scrot` you could make screenshot with unchanged colours? If yes that script should do the work and take screen of window that you want....

---

Script inspired on answers of @fred: [How do I find the window dimensions and position accurately including decorations?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/how-do-i-find-the-window-dimensions-and-position-accurately/14170#14170) and @JRW: [Oneliner for slicing an image?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10662/oneliner-for-slicing-an-image/10675#10675)

Comment: It works; there is no aberration, so it seems that `import` (imagemagick) is doing something differently to `scrot`. By the way, `scrot` can capture directly to `.pnm`; that saves one step, and there was an extra `xdotool` command (I've modified your answer). For my particular requirements, I'm still after a utility which grabs a window, because I want the the entire image, even when the window is partially covered. `import` does this, so I'm certainally still looking for something else which can grab a window by its ID... I'll keep the question open for a while yet. (netpbm looks interesting)

Comment: I just noticed that @JRW in his *"Oneliner for slicing an image?"* question, mentioned that *imagemagick* garbled his *mostly transparent* .png.... That sure sounds like my problem! ..thanks for link